# Connect Api-platform to External SSO like Oauth

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, api-platform.com

I have 2 applications which have the same architecture (Front, API, Back-office). Each application is built with the Symfony framework. APIs are built using Api-platform.
I also have several types of users: Administrators, moderators and users.
I would like that if my administrators or my moderators are connected on one application, they are also connected on the other.
So, I was thinking of setting up an SSO server as an OAuth server.

Is it a good idea to use an OAuth server?

Unfortunately, I don't know how to link my applications to this SSO server.
Can you help me?

Thank you in advance